# How to change the value of a JQueryUI progressbar dynamically?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, progress-bar

In my import photos script, I try to update a progressbar (Jquery UI) following a while loop with Ajax requests.

The JQueryUI progressbar, which is supposed to be displayed before the launch of ajax requests do it after. So I have the user feedback at the end of the execution of my while loop ... (The console shows me that these applications are running well, in the right order)

I thought about using live () or bind (), but I do not know how to test it ...

Here is my jquery code:

```
    $(function() {

    var percent_progressbar=0;

    $('#myform').submit(function() {

        $('#myform').hide(); 
        $("#text_result").html("Import in progress : <span class='progression'>0/0</span>").show(10, function() {

        $("#myprogressbar").progressbar({value:percent_progressbar});           
        $("#myprogressbar").show(10, function() {

            if (jQuery.trim($("#id_src").val()).length!=0) {
            // Total number of photos to import
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                async : false,
                url : '/nbphotos.php',
                data : 'chem=mydir',
                success : function(nbphotos){
                if (nbphotos>0){
                    $(".progression").html("0"+" / "+nbphotos);

                    var finish=false;
                    var nb_photos_imported=0;
                    var ajax_done = false;
                    var resultat_ajax="";
                    // Variables envoyées en Ajax
                    var datas = desvariables;
                    while (nb_photos_imported < nbphotos) {

                        ajax_done = false;

                        $.ajax({
                        type : 'GET',
                        async : false,
                        url : '/traitement.php',
                        data : datas,
                        success : function(resultat){
                            resultat_ajax=resultat;
                            ajax_done=true;
                            nb_photos_imported++;
                        }
                        });

                        if (ajax_done==true){
                        if (resultat_ajax=="ok") {
                            percent_progressbar = Math.floor(nb_photos_imported*100/nbphotos);
                            $("#myprogressbar").progressbar("option", "value", percent_progressbar);
                            console.info("Succès ajax (resultat : OK) : "+percent_progressbar);
                            $(".progression").html(nb_photos_imported+" / "+nbphotos);
                        } else {
                            finish=true;
                            $("#text_result").html(ajax_done);
                            return false;
                        }                   
                        } else {
                        // ajax error => exit the while
                        console.info("Ajax execution error "+nb_photos_imported);
                        return false;
                        }                   
                    } // While

                    if (finish==true) {
                        $("#myprogressbar").hide('slow');
                        $('#text_result').html("Import of "+nb_photos_imported+" photos done.");
                    }

                } else{
                    $("#text_result").html("No photo to import.");              
                    $("#myprogressbar").hide(10);
                    $('#myform').show("slow"); 
                }
                }
            });
            }
        });
        }); // callback #text_result.show()

        return false;
    });


    });
```

Comment: Don't have the time for a complete answer atm., sorry. / Hence in all brevity a few observations: You're setting `ajax_done = true;` and `nb_photos_imported++;` in the success callback, but checking against it right after defining the ajax request. The result will not be accurate, since most (all) requests won't be even finished before you're running the last check. I'd recommend to look in jQuery's deferred object API: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ . Maybe that can give you an idea on how to solve this better. Post if you're making changes, I'll try to write an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new code. The console log show the progression of the percentage, the photos are imported, but I still have the display at the end. If I put a breakpoint with me debugging tool somewhere in the loop, the display is refreshing and everything is OK...

```
$(function () {

    $("#myprogressbar").show();

    var RetourNbPhotos = "";
    var RetourImported = "";
    var fini = false;
    var percent_progressbar = 0;
    var nb_photos_imported = 0;
    var datas = desvariables; // datas sent with ajax
    // Number of photos to import
    function NbPhotoAjax() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: '/boutique/modules/importimageswithiptc/ajax-nbphotos.php',
            data: 'chem=$cheminimport',
            success: function (nbphotos) {
                RetourNbPhotos = nbphotos;
            }
        });
    }

    // Photo Ajax Import
    function ImportPhotoAjax() {

        $("#text_result").html("Import in progress : <span class='progression'>0/0</span>").show();

        // RetourImported = "";
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: '/boutique/modules/importimageswithiptc/ajax-traitement.php',
            data: datas,
            success: function (resultat) {
                RetourImported = resultat;
            }
        });
    }

    $("#myprogressbar").progressbar({
        value: percent_progressbar
    });

    $('#generator').submit(function () {
        $('#generator').hide();
        if (jQuery.trim($("#id_product_src").val()).length != 0) {

            $.when(NbPhotoAjax()).then(function () {
                if (RetourNbPhotos > 0) {
                    while (nb_photos_imported < RetourNbPhotos) {
                        $.when(ImportPhotoAjax()).then(function () {
                            nb_photos_imported++;
                            if (RetourImported == "ok") {
                                percent_progressbar = Math.floor(nb_photos_imported * 100 / RetourNbPhotos);
                                $("#myprogressbar").progressbar("option", "value", percent_progressbar);
                                console.info("Success : " + percent_progressbar + "%");
                                $(".progression").html(nb_photos_imported + " / " + RetourNbPhotos);
                            } else {
                                fini = true;
                                $("#text_result").html("ajax_reussi");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }).fail(function () {
                            //  ajax error => exit the while
                            console.info("Ajax execution error " + nb_photos_imported);
                            return false;
                        });
                    } // While
                    if (fini == true) {
                        $("#myprogressbar").hide('slow');
                        $('#text_result').html("Import of " + nb_photos_imported + " photos done.");
                    }

                } else {
                    $("#text_result").html("No photo to import.");

                    $("#myprogressbar").hide(10);
                    $('#generator').show("slow");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display at the end"? (Btw.: You can edit/extend your original question if you try something new. Since your current version still doesn't work, this doesn't really qualify as "answer" and might keep you from getting other answers.)

Comment: I click on the submit button. The screen don't change. The ajax queries are running well (console log display the 'Success' message)  Then, at the end, my screen change and my progressbar (complete) display.